# Change EditorTemplates folder location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

About what I read, the EditorTemplates folder must be located under the Shared folder in the Views folder. Is it possible to change this location?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always placed my `EditorTemplates` beneath each view folder they were related too. For example:

[image: Editor Templates]

If they were "shared" across multiple views I would place them within the "Shared/EditorTemplates" folder.

Comment: Hi Jesse. First, thank you very much for this answer. I tried what you said but when I enter the string representing the view in visual studio, there is no underline like all common views. Is this a bug of visual studio or a missing feature? Do you have the same problem? How do you write the string for referencing the editor template?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to change this location?

No, that's hardcoded in the MVC source code. Sorry.

Comment: While the name of the "EditorTemplates" folder is hard coded, from my experience the location of that folder can be moved.

Comment: The "EditorTemplates" substring is hardcoded, but the path to it isn't - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22062735/633626.