# ASP.NET MVC 5.1 EditorFor and DisplayFor not Using Custom Templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

suddenly my MVC application stopped using the custom `EditorFor` or `DisplayFor` templates I have. I'm not sure when exactly it failed since I've been changing the UI. I have the templates sitting in `DisplayTemplates` and `EditorTemplates` under the `Shared` folder. I do override the `ViewEnginesCollection` in `Global.asax` with this:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CSHtmlRazorViewEngine {
    PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] { 
        "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml"
    }
});
```

Where `CSHtmlRazorViewEngine` is:

```
public sealed class CSHtmlRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine {
    public CSHtmlRazorViewEngine()
        : base() {
        this.AreaViewLocationFormats = new string[2] {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        this.AreaMasterLocationFormats = new string[2] {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        this.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new string[2] {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        this.ViewLocationFormats = new string[3] {
            "~/Views/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        this.MasterLocationFormats = new string[2] {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        this.PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[2] {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        this.FileExtensions = new string[1] {
            "cshtml"
        };
    }
}
```

I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding where I've gone wrong all of the sudden. Any recommendations on where to check for what?

**UPDATE - Code Examples**

Here's the `Edit.cshtml` page for an `Office` object:

```
<div class="Section">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Offices", new {
        id = Model.Office.Id
    }, FormMethod.Post)) {
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Office, new {
            Regions = Model.Regions,
            States = Model.States
        })
    }
    @Html.Partial("Equipments", Model.Equipments)
</div>
```

And here's the `EditorFor` template for `Office` that's being requested:

```
@model Office
<p>
    @Html.Label("Name", "Name:")
    @Html.TextBox("Name", Model.Name, new {
        required = string.Empty
    })
</p>
<p>
    @Html.Label("RegionId", "Region:")
    @Html.DropDownList("RegionId", new SelectList((IEnumerable<Region>)ViewData["Regions"], "Id", "Name", Model.RegionId), string.Empty, new {
        required = string.Empty
    })
</p>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Address)
```

And here's the `OfficesController.Edit() ActionResult`:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(
    short id) {
    if (id > 0) {
        Office office = await base.Repository.FindSingleOrDefaultAsync<Office, short>(id);

        if (office != null) {
            Task<IQueryable<Equipment>> equipments = Task.Run(() => base.Repository.FindEquipment<Office>(id));
            Task<IQueryable<Region>> regions = Task.Run(() => base.Repository.Find<Region>());
            Task<IQueryable<State>> states = Task.Run(() => base.Repository.Find<State>());

            await Task.WhenAll(equipments, regions, states);

            return base.View(new OfficesView {
                Equipments = equipments.Result.ToList(),
                Office = office,
                Regions = regions.Result,
                States = states.Result,
                ViewData = new OfficeViewData {
                    Map = new Map {
                        Center = office.Address.Position.ToPoint(),
                        Polygons = (office.Boundaries != null) ? new Polygon[] {
                            office.Boundaries.ToPolygon()
                        } : null
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    return base.RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

There are no compilation or run-time exceptions being generated. The `EditorFor` just silently fails to find the template and generates the default one instead. The code pattern pretty much repeats for every other object.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions that it cannot find the view (i.e. the template)? Because if you are not getting any exceptions, the problem is not with your view locations, but elsewhere.

Comment: No, no exceptions, instead I just get the default generated editor for the object.

Comment: Can you maybe post a snippet of a form that uses one of your display and / or editor template, and the name of the display / editor template and possible if your data models / properties are decorated with `[UIHint]` a snippet of that.

Comment: @jacqijvv, I've updated my question with the code examples.

Comment: So just to make sure one more time, your editor template naming convention is `Office.cshtml` for the `Office` object, and `Address.cshtml` for the `Address` object etc?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48543/discussion-between-jacqijvv-and-alex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC will add itself the `EditorTemplates/` segment to the partial view name when looking for an editor template. You can check the source [code here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/TemplateHelpers.cs), ExecuteTemplate function.

You have set the partial view locations as:

```
"~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/{0}.cshtml"
"~/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml"
```

When looking for the `Address` editor template, MVC will use `EditorTemplates/Address` as the partial view name. That means it will check the 2 following partial view locations:

```
~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/EditorTemplates/Address.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Partials/EditorTemplates/Address.cshtml
```

If it cannot find them there, it will go back the default editor templates.

Probably your editor templates are sitting currently in the first EditorTemplates folder?

Comment: Yup, that was it. What resolved the issue for me was when I moved the `"~/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml"` format out of the init for the `CSHtmlRazorViewEngine` and directly into the class. Then in `Global.asax`, I just left it with an empty init and it all started working again.